# About these goddesses mentioned in Agni Purana

Tags: identification-request, goddess

This chapter of Agni Purana mentiones four goddess, Rudracarcika, Rudrachamunda, Siddha Chamunda and Siddhayogeshvari.

> 30-31. (The image of) **Rudracarcikā** (the manifestation of) the goddess may have a bow adorned by the plume of peacock, club, banner, protective posture, cock, skull, scissors, trident and noose in the right and left hands. (She should also be) clad in the elephant hide, with her leg raised up and the little drum placed on the head.
>
> 32.Hence she (is known as) **Rudracāmuṇḍā**, the goddess of dancing and one who is dancing. This (goddess herself), having four faces and in the sitting posture (is known as) Mahālakṣmī.
>
> 33-34. (The goddess) having ten hands and three eyes (holding) (different) weapons, sword and ḍamaru (little drum) in the right hand and the bell, club, staff with a skull at one end and trident in the left (hand) and eating men, horses, buffaloes and elephants held in the hand is called **Siddhacāmuṇḍā**.
>
> 35.That goddess accomplishes everything and is (known (as) **Siddhayogeśvarī**. She is also represented in another form endowed with the noose and goad and red (in complexion).

I wanted to know about these 4 goddesses. So, my question is, Who are these goddesses and Is any other scriptures mention about them?